# Meta Tag Redirect Stuck In Browser Cache

Tags: html, redirect, meta-tags

I recently started working with a client that had an index.html file with this in the head:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1; url=http://example.com/">
```

I deleted this file and added my own index.php file, but mine is being completely ignored because the html page with the redirect seems to be cached by the browser. I know how to get rid of this for me, but is there a way to force the redirect to not occur? This will be in many users cache, just like it was for mine.

For the record, I don't setup my redirects this way, because of this exact issue. I am dealing with someone else's code from a long time ago.

So, am I out of luck until user's caches are cleared or expire? Or is there anything I can do, perhaps with .htaccess, to fix this problem?

WordPress will ultimately be used on this project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use .htaccess to redirect to another page that defines no cache for the site, then redirect back to the original index file that was cached.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="cache-control" CONTENT="no-cache">
```

Comment: That would work if they had put that in the index.html file beforehand, but they didn't. I use cache control for my redirects (not through meta, but through headers sent with PHP).

So, I need an after the fact fix for code that didn't plan for browser caching.

Comment: when there has been also no expires set on the older version than you can only wait till the users browser cache is full.